# Edit.GotoBrace shortcut for Visual Basic (Visual Studio)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 Professional. There is a nice keyboard shortcut for C/C++ and C# code which takes you to start/end brace. This can be found at `Options > Environment > Keyboard > Edit.GotoBrace` which is configured to `Ctrl+]` on my installation:

```
if (something)
{ // <= Press CTRL+] here...
    SomeFunction();
    AnotherFunction();
} // <= ...and get taken here (or vice versa). Nice!
```

Is there something similar for Visual Basic.NET? The `Edit.GotoBrace` shortcut does not work.

```
If (something) Then ' <= I'd like to press CTRL+] here...
    SomeFunction()
    AnotherFunction()
End If ' <= ...and be taken here (and vice versa)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click one of the `If`, `Then`, `Else` or `End If`, and all of them will be highlighted. This also works with `Try` and `Catch` (and other related keywords).

Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> to jump between highlighted references and keywords.

The shortcuts are `Edit.PreviousHighlightedReference` and `Edit.NextHighlightedReference`, which can be found in `Options > Environment > Keyboard`.

Note that keyword highlighting must be enabled in `Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced > Highlighting > Highlight related keywords under cursor`.

Comment: You can consider [resetting environment settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings), and then test again.